# why do we need to run selenium standalone server for webdriverjs tests?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriver-io

from selenium docs https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#webdriver-and-the-selenium-server we don't need to run selenium-server if we are using webdriver but almost all javascript automation frameworks need selenium-server to be started before running tests.  why do we need to run selenium standalone server for webdriverjs tests ?

Comment: Interesting. I never knew this and now I'm intrigued. Hopefully this gets some good discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Given your browser/ driver pair supports directConnect. It will run without the selenium server regardless of the language binding.

For instance, Here is the directConnect reference for protractor. https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/server-setup.md#connecting-directly-to-browser-drivers